# Loading the operating system to the USB drive for Mac

Tags: system-installation

Execute sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.imgor ./ubuntu.dmg).

What does this mean example: in terminal I would type

sudo dd if=/Users/Me/Desktop/ubuntu.img of/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m/Users/Me/Desktop/ubuntu.img

is this correct or wouldn't be something different I don't understand the terminology

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

You run the `dd` command in Terminal.  As it notes, **make sure you have the right disk** (as it'll overwrite whatever is on there).  If your disk is /dev/rdisk3, then the command is:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/Me/Desktop/ubuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m
```